# Is the helium atom with only a contact interaction between the electrons solvable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

Consider the hamiltonian for a helium atom,
$$
H=\frac12\mathbf p_1^2+\frac12\mathbf p_2^2 - \frac{2}{r_1}-\frac{2}{r_2} + a \, \delta(\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2),
$$
where I have taken out the electrostatic interactions between the two electrons and changed it to a contact interaction of strength $a$ to try and simplify things.

I would like to know to what extent this model is solvable, and if possible to what extent it has been explored in the literature. It is a natural thing to try, but it is also likely to be buried under the (more relevant) physics of actual electrostatic interactions between the electrons, so who knows what's out there.

I ask because, as I mentioned in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/313940/why-are-doubly-excited-states-in-helium-not-square-integrable/313953#313953), this is a very simple model that is still likely to show autoionization for all doubly excited states, as normal helium does, and it's a good test case to see how that comes about and what the bare-bones features of that mechanism actually are.

As such, I'm interested in

- what one can say about the ground and singly excited states in a Hartree-Fock perspective,
- to what extent one can fully solve the two-body Schrödinger equation for bound states with this interaction,
- how the different Hartree-Fock configurations look like for the doubly excited states as well as the corresponding singly ionized continua at those energies,
- how the Fano mechanism uses the entangling contact interaction to couple those two sectors, and what the resulting Fano resonances look like, and
- whether the simplified interaction lets us say more about those autoionizing resonances beyond what one can say via the Fano theory.

As mentioned in the comments, this localized contact interaction is unlikely to impose autoionization on double excitations that have an exchange-symmetric spin state (since then the spatial part is antisymmetric and the electrons never coincide), so the main thrust of the question is on the (antisymmetric) spin singlet states, where the nontrivial physics should happen.

Comment: At least half of the states is as simple as in the case of $a=0$: the ones antisymmetric with respect to exchange of electrons. So at least those doubly-excited states having this property will not be auto-ionizing.

Comment: @Ruslan You mean those with a symmetric spin part, but yes, you're correct.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty See http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/24826/84967 In short: $V(\vec r)\propto \delta(\vec r-\vec a)$ is an ill-defined potential.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Note that this is a repulsive, not an attractive, delta-function potential, which makes the arguments in that answer moot. I can't rule out more fundamental problems, though - can you comment on those?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform you're mistaking $\delta(|\vec r_1-\vec r_2|)$ for 6D delta with point support $\delta(|\vec r-\vec a|)$ where $\vec a$ is a point. The delta-potential here has a hypersurface as singular support: all the points in 6D space where $\vec r_1=\vec r_2$. For a simpler example, compare $\delta(y)$ in 2D space vs $\delta(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$: the former is more like the potential here, while the latter is more like the potential discussed in your link.

Comment: For a simple discussion of he He atom see my answer at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/687957/wavefunctions-of-an-n-electron-atom/794779#794779.

Comment: Well, this contact interaction is basically the starting point in order to derive the Gross-Pitaevskii equation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross%E2%80%93Pitaevskii_equation
in case of N *bosons*. There are also some considerations found for fermions in 1 spatial dimension in https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jmp/article/1/6/516/222573/Relationship-between-Systems-of-Impenetrable

Answer (score 0):

Note that for the less relevant case of $a \lt 0$ the problem may be ill-posed, depending on he size of $a$. See @EmilioPisanty's comment. Otherwise this model is solvable for triplets and perhaps also for singlets.

For triplets, just solve the hydrogenlike equation with Z=2 and occupy two different orbitals. This works as there is no interaction at all between the electrons.

For singlets and $a=0$ the result is the same as for triplets, except that you can also put both electrons in the *same* orbital or, generally, in partially overlapping orbitals. If $a \gt 0$ a repulsive $a|\psi|^4$ interaction occurs. I don't know if an exact solution is known or possible. The [Kummer equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Kummer%27s_equation) unifies the Schrödinger, Dirac and Klein Gordon radial hydrogenlike equations. You could look for extensions of it with third order terms. However, this seems a disproportionate effort for what is just a toy model, when atomic MCHF solutions are widely available.

Note that very accurate solutions are achievable with [Hylleraas](https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/harrison/web_docs_He/Hylleraas_wavefunction.pdf) functionals.

As a further note, while it is possible to write down the solutions of the Schrödinger equation, this itself is only an approximation. For accuracy one should use the also exactly soluble Dirac equation, augmented with QED corrections. Also there are hyperfine interactions with nuclear moments and the effect of finite nuclear size to consider.

Comment: How is "accuracy" at all relevant for a toy model like the one at hand? I suspect the qualitative discussion here is accurate, but the OP is asking for rather more detail than that.

Comment: On terminology: your linked pdf shows Hylleraas-type explicitly correlated basis functions, but the name Hylleraas functional itself is reserved for a different thing, a variational approach to accurately calculate sum-over-states expressions, e.g. in perturbative corrections. The Hylleraas functional technique is used for example to get as close to the complete basis limit of PT corrections as possible. See e.g. *Simple Theorems, Proofs and Derivations in Quantum Chemistry* by Mayer.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty You can always ask for more detail but I doubt that anyone ever worked this out. Why would you if you have Froese Fischer’s MCHF and Dirac versions of it such as listed at https://nlte.nist.gov/MCHF/.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Admittedly, I do not answer the question whether this toy model is solvable. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -8):

There is a fuzzy wave fucntion solution.

1. When electrons are at the same distance from the nucleus. Then
   the coordinates of both electrons are linked, as soon as delta de
   Kronecker is 1.
2. When energy of both electrons are independent eachother,
   because both distances to nucleus are not equal. Then delta de
   Kronecker is zero.
3. Special case when repulsive Coulomb interaction between
   electrons is minimal. This is two blade electrons.

$$\vec{r_1} = -\vec{r_2}$$

First case fullfills next Schödinger Equation. Two times the hamiltonian of hydrogen-like with Z=2 atom, considering constant$$a_n =\frac{e}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left\langle\psi_1\left|\frac{1}{r_{12}}\right|\psi_1\right\rangle=\frac{e}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left\langle R_n(r)\left|\frac{1}{r}\right|R_n(r)\right\rangle \hspace{0.1in} for \hspace{0.1in} l=0$$ where in the denominator stays the distance between *He* electrons.

$$2H_{Z=2}\psi_1=(E-a_n) \psi_1 = p^2-\frac{4}{r}$$where the energy levels only depends on the radius, for these reason is considered twice the kinetic energy, then $$E-a_n = \frac{-108.8}{n^2}$$  and the result in eV is $$E = \frac{-108.8}{n^2}+a_n \hspace{0.1 in}(eV)$$

Next case, is the energies of two electrons with independent coordinates atracted by the nucleus with Z=2.

$$E =\frac{-54.4}{n_1^2} - \frac{54.4}{n_2^2} \hspace{0.1in}(eV)$$ and none electron repulsion is considered, because of delta Kronecker is zero. And wave function is the product of the electron wave functions $$\psi_2=\psi_{21}\hspace{0.1in}\psi_{22}$$

And finally, a singularity from the first case, with analytical resolution with electron repulsion, is when $$a \hspace{0.1in}\delta(r_1-r_2) =\frac{1}{2r}$$, that is two blade electrons. It could be obtained next energy levels. Twice the level energies of hydrogen-like atom with $$Z=\frac{7}{4}=2-\frac{1}{4}$$

$$E = -\frac{83.3}{n^2} \hspace{0.1 in}(eV)$$

because $$H\psi_3=\left(2\frac{p^2}{2}-2\frac{2}{r}+\frac{1}{2r}\right)\psi_3$$
That solves the Schödinger equation raised above. No Hartree-Fock statements are applied. Perhaps this Fuzzy Wave Function and related energy levels could explain Fano resonance of *He*.

Comment: This is largely word salad, I'm sorry to say. From its contents, it appears quite unlikely to be what was asked for, but it cannot even be evaluated in its current form -- the answer needs to be substantially be edited for clarity before its actual contents can be understood.